# Modify specific line of a file - Java

Tags: java

I want to know if it is possible in Java to modify a specific line from a text file. I have a text file which looks like this:

row1: 0

row2: 1

row3: 0

row4: 1

I am using this:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("seats.txt",true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write("2", 0, 1);
```

And the output is this:

row1: 0

row2: 1

row3: 0

row4: 12

etc.

If i set the offset to any other value than 0, i receive this exception:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2

Basically what i want to do is to switch the values. If i have "0" at row x, i want to put a "1"in there and vice versa. No other information will be stored on a line, only a 1 or a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset in the BufferedWrite.write() method is not an offset in the File you are trying to write into, but in the String you are in it.
If you check the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html you will see the following:

```
write(String s, int off, int len)
Writes a portion of a String.
```

So basically what you are doing is writting the String s from the character number off to the character number len-1.

What I would suggest (as far as I know) is creating a BufferedReader as well, read all the file, and then overwrite the existing file, checking each row at a time with some loops and conditionals and then writing the corresponding value.
You may use the write(int c) method instead, since you are only writing 0 or 1.

Comment: I have already used BufferedReader to read my file, but i did not thought to rewrite all the file with my modified array (arrays). Thanks, i will use your suggestion!